# How do I handle a database response as a list of objects?

Tags: python, oop, sqlite

I am making a SQL query like

```
"SELECT * FROM people"
```

in my python script and then the response is a list with a lot of people. I would like to wrap each people as an instance of my *people*-class and then make a list of that. Is this possible in some other way than loop through the database response and creating a second list?

For now I am using this to handle the database:

```
def get_db(self):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(database)
    return db

def query_db(self, query, args=(), one=False):
    cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    get_db().commit()
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv
```

The database is a sqlite3 database if that matters.

Comment: There are plenty of ORMs that do exactly this sort of thing - SqlAlchemy, SqlObject, PeeWee, Django, etc. Why not use one of them?

Comment: It seems like that is the right way to go! I will take a look at SQLAlchemy!